# Entity Framework loading all properties from relation

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-7.0

I am setting up an ASP.NET Core 7 Web API, with EF and SQL Server.

What I want: the entity that I need + a 2 properties from a relation.

```
var list = 
    await _dataContext.AdvertiserConcerns
                      .Include(ac => ac.Concern)
                      .Select(ac => new
                                   {
                                       ac,
                                       ac.Concern.ContactId,
                                       ac.Concern.Name
                                   })
                      .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Which is actually retrieving all the properties from "concern".

If I do this:

```
var list = 
    await _dataContext.AdvertiserConcerns
                      .Include(ac => ac.Concern)
                      .Select(ac => new
                                    {
                                        ac.ConcernId,
                                        ac.AdvertiserId,
                                        ac.StartDate,
                                        ac.EndDate,
                                        ac.Concern.ContactId,
                                        ac.Concern.Name
                                    })
                      .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Then it is working as expected. I was not expecting to list all properties from AC.

Is it something that I am overlooking?

My class from AC:

```
public class AdvertiserConcern : Entity
{
    public required int ConcernId { get;set; }
    public required int AdvertiserId { get;set; }
    public required DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
    public string? Remark { get; set; }

    public Client? Concern { get; set; }
    public Client? Advertiser { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: *Is it something that I am overlooking?* Nope. This has been asked in many forms (I'm too lazy to look for duplicates). There's not something like `SELECT *` in LINQ.

Comment: that is a shame! I thought from a few years ago that was they it worked. but I guess time forgets implementations ;)  I guess in EF 7 there is still no way to map the select directly to the objects right? (instead of anonymous object)

Comment: No there isn't. That's where AutoMapper brings some relief. BTW, you don't need the `Include`, the projection fully determines what ends up in the generated SQL.